# How to add ajax property to an existing field in a content type in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created content type with several fields. I want to add an ajax property to some fields in that content type using `hook_form_alter`.

Is there any way to inject the ajax property to an existing field if I know the machine name of that field?

Is there any way to update an existing field state using ajax?

How can I do this programatically?